# C - getopt_long() example - tests in case 0

Tags: c, gnu, getopt-long

I would like to use getopt_long() correctly and am trying to understand why certain choices were made in the [example of getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html#Getopt-Long-Option-Example). (I've copied the full code listing below).

I understand that case 0 occurs when the flag field of the struct is not null ([find getopt_long returns 0](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options)), but **why does the example show retesting** `long_options[option_index].flag` for null **in case 0**? Isn't this guaranteed given that we are in case 0?

**Asked another way:** What input could I provide to cause the code to enter case 0 but fail the first if-statement within it? Is `printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);` unreachable?

---

**25.2.4 Example of Parsing Long Options with `getopt_long`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

/* Flag set by ‘--verbose’. */
static int verbose_flag;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;

  while (1)
    {
      static struct option long_options[] =
      {
        /* These options set a flag. */
        {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},
        {"brief",   no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 0},
        /* These options don’t set a flag.
           We distinguish them by their indices. */
        {"add",     no_argument,       0, 'a'},
        {"append",  no_argument,       0, 'b'},
        {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
        {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
        {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
      };
    /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
    int option_index = 0;

    c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "abc:d:f:", long_options, &option_index);

    /* Detect the end of the options. */
    if (c == -1)
      break;

    switch (c)
      {
      case 0:
        /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
        if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
          break;
        printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
        if (optarg)
          printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
        printf ("\n");
        break;

      case 'a':
        puts ("option -a\n");
        break;

      case 'b':
        puts ("option -b\n");
        break;

      case 'c':
        printf ("option -c with value `%s'\n", optarg);
        break;

      case 'd':
        printf ("option -d with value `%s'\n", optarg);
        break;

      case 'f':
        printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
        break;

      case '?':
        /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
        break;

      default:
        abort ();
      }
  }

/* Instead of reporting ‘--verbose’
   and ‘--brief’ as they are encountered,
   we report the final status resulting from them. */
if (verbose_flag)
  puts ("verbose flag is set");

/* Print any remaining command line arguments (not options). */
if (optind < argc)
  {
    printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
    while (optind < argc)
      printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
    putchar ('\n');
  }

exit (0);
```

}

Comment: Your example is old, it seems. Checking my local manual page, or [this online manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt_long.3.html) shows the example without that check.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimPileborg. I had seen this online manual but favoured the GNU one for the clear use of the flag/val fields in the `long_options` struct. Incidentally my local `man 3 getopt` page appears similar to the link you posted.